# Keep getting a error while using fminsearch

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization, fminsearch

simulate function code:

```
function [V] = simulate(I , params)
%parameters
alphaa = params(1);
k = params(2);
ka = params(3);
delb = params(4);
x4 = params(5);
x3 = params(6);
k3 = params(7);
alphac = params(8);
k6 = params(9);
x6 = params(10);
x5 = params(11);
V = 0.77 -(((0.026) ./ (alphaa)).*log((0.09191)./(k.*((((1.56) - ((0.103) .*I))./(ka + (1.56) - ((0.103) .*I))) + (((15.55) .*I .*delb .*(x4 - x3))./((k3 .*ka) + ((15.55) .*I .*delb .*(x4 - x3)))))))) - (((0.0261) ./alphac) .*log(((0.121) .*I)./(k6 .*(((1.85) .*10 .^-4 .*(x6 - x5)) ./ (((2.22) .*(x6 - x5)) - ((0.113) .*k6)))))) - ((0.000049) .*I);
end
```

calculate_objective function code:

```
function [value] = calculate_objective(parameters)
%CALCULATE_OBJECTIVE Summary of this function goes here
% Detailed explanation goes here
%loads a table containing 10 rows and 2 columns
load data.mat Dmodeldata;
predicted = simulate(Dmodeldata.Icell, parameters);
[num_rows, num_cols] = size(Dmodeldata.Vcell);
value = zeros(1,10);
for i = 1:num_rows
value = value + sum(((Dmodeldata.Vcell(i,:)) - predicted).^2);
end
end
```

Estimate_parameters script:

```
clear;
guess = [0.1,0.3,0.7,0.1,2,1,1,0.6,0.1,4,3];
options = optimset('Display', 'iter');
[solution.parameters] = ...
fminsearch(@calculate_objective, guess, options);
save solution.mat solution;
```

Error:

> Unable to perform assignment because the size of the left side is
> 1-by-1 and the size of the right side is 1-by-10.
>
> Error in fminsearch (line 200) fv(:,1) = funfcn(x,varargin{:});
>
> Error in estimate_parameters (line 9) fminsearch(@calculate_objective,
> guess, options);

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: General comment: Code that is a pain to read is a pain to debug. Good indentation and formatting makes your life easier.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Thank you for your comment. I just started to code in Matlab as you can tell. I will keep indentation in mind to improve my code readability

Comment: Found the error: Dmodeldata.Vcell(i,:) should be changed to Dmodeldata.Vcell and the code works

Comment: the error-messages of MATLAB are straight forward. They tell you *where*  something is wrong (function + line) and *what* is wrong (you want to assign an array to a scalar variable). You may want to read how to [debug](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html) with MATLAB for your future developments